# unable to append data using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use ajax in Laravel so that I can create post without reloading the page. Here is what I have done so far. I have created a controller
and stored the data as such

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $post=new Post();
       $post->user_id=auth()->user()->id;
       $post->content=$request->content;
       if($request->hasfile('image'))
        {
            $file=$request->file('image');
            $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename=time() ."." . $extension;
            $file->move('uploads/image',$filename);
            $post->image=$filename;

        }

       $post->save();
       return response()->json($post);
    }
```

I have also passed an ajax such as

```
<script>
$('#CreatePost').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
let content=$('#content').val();
let image=$('#image').val();
$.ajax({
    url:"{{route('home.store')}}",
    type:"POST",
    data:{
        content:content,
        image:image,
        _token:_token

    },
    sucess :function (response)
    if(response)
    {
        $('#showid').prepend('<div class="col-sm-12" id="showid">
                        <div class="iq-card iq-card-block iq-card-stretch iq-card-height">
                           <div class="iq-card-body">
                              <div class="post-item">
                                 <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
                                    <div class="media-support-user-img mr-3">
                                       <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="{{asset('assets/html/images/user/1.jpg')}}" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-support-info mt-2">
                                       <h5 class="mb-0 d-inline-block"><a href="#" class="">{{$posts->user->name}}</a></h5>
                                       <p class="ml-1 mb-0 d-inline-block"></p>
                                       <p class="mb-0">{{$posts->created_at}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="iq-card-post-toolbar">
                                       <div class="dropdown">
                                          <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button">
                                          <i class="ri-more-fill"></i>
                                          </span>
                                          <div class="dropdown-menu m-0 p-0">
                                             <a class="dropdown-item p-3" href="#">
                                                <div class="d-flex align-items-top">
                                                   <div class="icon font-size-20"><i class="ri-save-line"></i></div>
                                                   <div class="data ml-2">
                                                      <h6>Save Post</h6>
                                                      <p class="mb-0">Add this to your saved items</p>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                             </a>
                                             <a class="dropdown-item p-3" href="#">
                                                <div class="d-flex align-items-top">
                                                   <div class="icon font-size-20"><i class="ri-close-circle-line"></i></div>
                                                   <div class="data ml-2">
                                                      <h6>Hide Post</h6>
                                                      <p class="mb-0">See fewer posts like this.</p>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                             </a>
                                             <a class="dropdown-item p-3" href="#">
                                                <div class="d-flex align-items-top">
                                                   <div class="icon font-size-20"><i class="ri-user-unfollow-line"></i></div>
                                                   <div class="data ml-2">
                                                      <h6>Unfollow User</h6>
                                                      <p class="mb-0">Stop seeing posts but stay friends.</p>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                             </a>
                                             <a class="dropdown-item p-3" href="#">
                                                <div class="d-flex align-items-top">
                                                   <div class="icon font-size-20"><i class="ri-notification-line"></i></div>
                                                   <div class="data ml-2">
                                                      <h6>Notifications</h6>
                                                      <p class="mb-0">Turn on notifications for this post</p>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                             </a>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="user-post text-center">
                                 <a href="javascript:void();"><img src="{{asset('uploads/image/'.$posts->image)}}" alt="post-image" class="img-fluid rounded w-100 mt-3"></a>
                              </div>
                              <div class="comment-area mt-3">
                                 <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                    <div class="like-block position-relative d-flex align-items-center">
                                       <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                          <div class="like-data">
                                             <div class="dropdown">
                                                <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button">
                                                <img src="{{asset('assets/html/images/icon/01.png')}}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                                </span>
                                                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                                   <a class="ml-2 mr-2" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Like"><img src="{{asset('assets/html/images/icon/01.png')}}" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
                                                   <a class="mr-2" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Love"><img src="{{asset('assets/html/images/icon/02.png')}}" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
                                                   <a class="mr-2" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Happy"><img src="{{asset('assets/html/images/icon/03.png')}}" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
                                                   <a class="mr-2" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="HaHa"><img src="{{asset('assets/html/images/icon/04.png')}}" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
                                                   <a class="mr-2" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Think"><img src="{{asset('assets/html/images/icon/05.png')}}" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
                                                   <a class="mr-2" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Sade"><img src="{{asset('assets/html/images/icon/06.png')}}" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
                                                   <a class="mr-2" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Lovely"><img src="{{asset('assets/html/images/icon/07.png')}}" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="total-like-block ml-2 mr-3">
                                             <div class="dropdown">
                                                <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button">
                                                140 Likes
                                                </span>
                                                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Max Emum</a>

                                                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Other</a>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="total-comment-block">
                                          <div class="dropdown">
                                             <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button">
                                             20 Comment
                                             </span>
                                             <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Max Emum</a>

                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="share-block d-flex align-items-center feather-icon mr-3">
                                       <a href="javascript:void();"><i class="ri-share-line"></i>
                                       <span class="ml-1">99 Share</span></a>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr>
                                 
                                
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>');
                     $('#CreatePost')[0].reset();
    }
});
});



</script>
```

I want to show my data without reloading the page but I am unable to do so. All I am getting is my response in json which is

```json
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "content": "ya allah habibi",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-25T09:07:58.000000Z",
    "created_at": "2021-05-25T09:07:58.000000Z",
    "id": 18
}
```

Comment: Make sure to send your request using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: yes it is saving form data .

Comment: `FormData` is not "form data". I'm talking about the [content type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) "`multipart/form-data`".

Comment: added this field also result is still the same data is getting saved and it is returning data in json

Comment: Where did you add it?

Comment: $.ajax({
    url:"{{route('home.store')}}",
    type:"POST",
    content type:"multipart/form-data"

Comment: try doing dd($request->all()); in the store function to see how the request looks or Log::info(print_r($request->all()));

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) (automatically sets [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) "`multipart/form-data`")

```
$('#CreatePost').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
let content=$('#content').val();
let image=$('#image').val();
let file = $('#image').get(0).files[0];
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append('content', content);
fd.append('image', file, file.name);
fd.append('_token', _token);
$.ajax({
    url:"{{route('home.store')}}",
    type:"POST",
    data:fd,
    dataType: 'json',
    sucess :function (response)
    if(response)
    {
        $('#showid').prepend(/* your template */);
```

Comment: I added `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: still i am getting answer in the this format

Comment: {"user_id":1,"content":"mera ghum tera ghum","updated_at":"2021-05-25T10:00:58.000000Z","created_at":"2021-05-25T10:00:58.000000Z","id":27}

Comment: If that doesn't work, use `JSON.parse(response)`